# Generating LLVM code for 'lambda', 'define'

Tags: haskell, compiler-construction, lisp, language-design, llvm

So I now have a fairly complete LISP (scheme) interpreter written in haskell.  Just for fun I want to try to have it compile down to LLVM.  Most of the code generation seems pretty straight forward, but I'm at a loss as to how to generate code for a `lambda` expression (kind of important in lisp ;) ) and how to manage the heap when I encounter a `define` expression.

How might I generated code for these expressions?

Note: I can generate code for the body of the lambda expression, What is confusing me is how to "put" that code somewhere and make it callable.

Comment: You may want to implement an explicit lambda lifting pass prior to your code generation (and since it is Scheme, you're likely to be doing a CPS-transform prior to that). It will leave you with only the global functions and an explicit closure envoronments allocation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See Lennart's blog post: http://augustss.blogspot.com/2009/06/more-llvm-recently-someone-asked-me-on.html

Look at the `compileFunction` function. In particular, `newFunction` in the LLVM core: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/llvm/0.9.1.2/doc/html/LLVM-Core.html#g:23

Comment: The language that is compiled in the blog post is first order and doesn't handle closures at all. I don't see how that is helpful for compiling scheme lambdas.

Comment: @sepp2k You'll need to do closure conversion first, which I assume John is doing, since he's reading SICP.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't remember closure conversion being covered in SICP.